# Add extra data to recyclerView

Tags: java, android

I've just recently started to learn some coding, a little python and java.
I'm trying to make a whatsapp clone as a test, and I've hit a wall.

Basically I have a UID showing as the name of a group chat, and I want to swap it for a groupId I have saved in firebase at the same level as the Uid.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").child(chatId).child("info").child("groupId)

I've been following simcoder youtube video and there's a lot of checks and balances happening between user and chat UIDs and I'm getting lost in the middle of all that.

I've tried adding groupId to the adapter and the chatObject, and I can see the data in debug, but I just can't get it to populate the recycler view. I've had a search of the forums here, but can't quite get it to work.

I'm hoping someone can help me out, many thanks

```
    private RecyclerView mChatList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mChatListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mChatListLayoutManager;

    ArrayList<ChatObject> chatList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_chat);

        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
        OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
            @Override
            public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("notificationKey").setValue(userId);
            }
        });
        OneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);

        Button mLogout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        Button mFindUser = findViewById(R.id.finduser);
        mFindUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FindUserActivity.class));
            }
        });
        mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;

            }
        });

        getPermissions();
        initializeRecyclerView();
        getUserChatList();
    }

    private void getUserChatList(){
        DatabaseReference mUserChatDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child("chat");

        mUserChatDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        ChatObject mChat = new ChatObject(childSnapshot.getKey());
                        boolean  exists = false;
                        for (ChatObject mChatIterator : chatList){
                            if(mChatIterator.getChatId().equals(mChat.getChatId()))
                                exists = true;
                        }
                        if (exists)
                            continue;
                        chatList.add(mChat);
                        getChatData(mChat.getChatId());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }



    private void getChatData(String chatId) {
        DatabaseReference mChatDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").child(chatId).child("info");
        mChatDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String chatId = "";
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue() != null)
                        chatId = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();

                    for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()){
                        for(ChatObject mChat : chatList)
                            if(mChat.getChatId().equals(chatId)){
                                UserObject mUser = new UserObject(userSnapshot.getKey());
                                mChat.addUserToArrayList(mUser);
                                getUserData(mUser);

                            }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void getUserData(UserObject mUser) {
        DatabaseReference mUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(mUser.getUid());
        mUserDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                UserObject mUser = new UserObject(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                if(dataSnapshot.child("notificationKey").getValue() != null)
                    mUser.setNotificationKey(dataSnapshot.child("notificationKey").getValue().toString());

                for(ChatObject mChat : chatList)
                    for(UserObject mUserIt : mChat.getUserObjectArrayList()){
                        if(mUserIt.getUid().equals(mUser.getUid())){
                            mUserIt.setNotificationKey(mUser.getNotificationKey());

                        }

                    }
                mChatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {
        chatList = new ArrayList<>();
        mChatList = findViewById(R.id.chatList);
        mChatList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mChatList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mChatListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
        mChatList.setLayoutManager(mChatListLayoutManager);
        mChatListAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(chatList);
        mChatList.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you are passing to the adapter an empty list so that's why there's not data to be displayed.
And also, where you are using `mChatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, you don't set before a populated list to the adapter.

I'm not sure which is the data you want to display but you have to collect in a list from the firebase all the information you want to display, for example, if `UserObject` is what you want, you have to make an `ArrayList<UserObject>`, to add there all the objects, pass it to the adapter and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` .

You can make function in the adapter, like :

```
public void setData(ArrayList<YourObject> list){
    yourAdapterList = list
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And then call it from your activity/fragment like `adapter.setData( /* your populated list */)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have an ArrayList<ChatObject> chatList; and it's dislaying a UID from getChatData. It's just not the data I'm hoping to display. I'm trying to add the groupId to the chatList, I just haven't figured that out, I will try your suggestion as a new function and see if that works.

Comment: Ok I got it working, thanks to your help.. by doing this..         if(dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue() != null)
                        chatId = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("groupName").getValue() != null)
                        groupId = dataSnapshot.child("groupName").getValue().toString();
                    ChatObject mGroup = new ChatObject(chatId, groupId);
                    chatList.add(mGroup);